# Customizing the password_resets table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to customize the multi-auth in Laravel 5.5.

I have a clients_password_resets table that has following columns

> clients_email,  token   created_at.

But when I submit the form to send password reset link I am getting the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'
(SQL: delete from `clients_password_resets` where `email` is null)
```

Comment: did you tried any one of the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize, but why are you naming the column **clients_email** instead of simple name **email**. Simply change the column name **clients_email**  to **email**.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your field name is `clients_email` and you are passing `email` in `where()` clause try this way

```
YourModelName::where('client_email', null)->delete();
```